# Get last three dates from the most recent date in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
      Reference Number        Date             Time                  
36566             5221  2022-09-12  16:26:11.359962  
36565             5220  2022-09-12  16:24:30.494203  
34773             5218  2022-09-11  14:44:41.524015  
34781             5218  2022-09-11  14:44:41.524015  
34780             5218  2022-09-11  14:44:41.524015  
...                ...         ...              ...           
94                5001  2022-05-12  12:14:20.100192    
95                5001  2022-05-12  12:14:20.100192    
96                5001  2022-05-12  12:14:20.100192    
97                5001  2022-05-12  12:14:20.100192    
4                 5000  2022-05-12  12:08:11.946828
```

How can I retrieve rows with the last three days from the most recent date ?

for example in this scenario I want the objects from `2022-09-12` to `2022-09-10`
The object type is `<class 'datetime.date'>`

I tried print("last day",df['Date'].iloc[-1]-datetime.timedelta(days=3))
but it says

> type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index().last('3D')
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df = df[df['Date'] > (df['Date'].max()-pd.Timedelta(days=3))]
```

Comment: I tried, it says TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index

Comment: @YantraLogistics - sure, there is `df.set_index('Date')`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Reference": [36566, 36565,34773],"Number": [5221, 5220,5218],"date": ["2019-3-18", "2019-10-24", "2019-1-1"]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.sort_values(by="date")
print(df[-2:])
```